# Inserting data into MySQL db using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am passing an array to a query. However, I can't seem to add each value `.

The array Im passing is:

```
Array ( 
        [name] => Name 
        [address_1] => Address 1 
        [address_2] => Address 2 
        [address_3] => Address 3 
        [address_4] => Address 4 
        [post_code] => Post COde 
        [proptype] => rent 
        [style] => house 
        [beds] => 1 
        [bathrooms] => 1 
        [garden] => 1 
        [furnished] => yes 
        [deposit] => Deposit 
        [available] => 10/18/2013 
        [description] => Description 
      )
```

Below is my code:

```
    foreach ($data as $column => $value) {
            $columns .= ($columns == "") ? "" : ", ";
            $columns .= $column;
            $values .= ($values == "") ? "" : ", ";
            $values .= $value;
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table ($columns) VALUES ($values)";

    echo "--->" . $sql;
    exit;
```

I know I need to enclose each value but I can't see where I need to do this.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: unless your values are all numeric, you'll have to enclose them in single quotes ', this is safe for numeric values also. '1' will be converted to 1 when inserting to a numeric field

Comment: !PLEASE! !USE! !PDO! http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php Don't ask why, just do it. You can read that up later.

Comment: agree with @nietonfir :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
foreach ($data as $column => $value) {
    $columns .= ($columns == "") ? "" : ", ";
    $columns .= $column;
    $values .= ($values == "") ? "" : ", ";
    $values .= "'" . $value . "'";
}
```

Comment: t-coder thanks for the quick reply. I managed to get it working with your help.

I added:

        foreach ($data as $column => $value) {
                $columns .= ($columns == "") ? "" : ", ";
                $columns .= $column;
                $values .= ($values == "") ? "" : ", ";
                $values .= "'" . $value . "'";
        }
        
        $sql = "INSERT INTO $table ($columns) VALUES ($values)";

Answer (score 0):

You could also to use a few built-in php functions:

```
// join column names with a comma
$columns = join(array_keys($data),',');

// pass every value through mysql-escape and join the values with quotes and commas
$values = join(array_map("mysql_real_escape_string",array_values($data)),'","');

// use the produced strings; make sure you wrap the values string with double quotes
$sql = "INSERT INTO $table ($columns) VALUES (\"$values\")";
```

For reference:
[array_keys](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php), 
[array_values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php), 
[array_map](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), [join](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.join.php)

I am using mysql_real_escape_string for security reasons.

Comment: I think using this query also data will not get added... see my answer... might be the reason I specified is what is happening...

Comment: @FahimParkar I am pretty sure the query **will** work if the values match the column types. Regarding your answer, I don't fully get it TBH, but in any case, your proposal to use "INSERT INTO tableName VALUES $value;" will only work if the array contains **all** columns.

Comment: why it will insert? for loop will go to insert name.. right? now when loop is trying to insert name, at that time rest fields are null... if OP have set all fields to be not null, then mysql will throw exception... **this is just my thoughts. What u think?**

Comment: @FahimParkar the loops are there to **construct** the query, not run it on every iteration. The query is supposed to **run once** at the end, after it's constructed. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Opps, I missed that totally... :D :P. I will delete my answer first before I get downvotes :D :P

Comment: `$values .= "'" . $value . "'";` OP answer is solved... check t-coder answer :D :P

Comment: @FahimParkar I would still prefer to use php's built-in functions. A matter of taste for sure.